# Safari iPhone sometimes increases font size when going back

Tags: css, iphone, font-size

I've made a webpage for myself: http://av.nettfolk.no/

When I use Safari on my iPhone (5 and 6, 9.2.1), tap on a link to a certain site (Inma), and then go back to my site, some fonts increase in size.

For the other sites, they don't change when I go back to my site.

If I visit this certain site, and go two pages deep, then go back two steps to my site, then the fonts are the right size.

I've tried a bunch of things, but I just can get this to work.

Does anyone know why this is and how I can fix it?

Comment: Is this ios- or iphone related? Please get your tags straight.

Answer (score 1):

It worked when I double checked one of my previous attempts and found that I had written a line wrong. This worked:
`html {-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;}`

I never found out why Safari only enlarged the fonts when I was coming back from certain sites.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I wonder if the =viewport doesn't have quotes upsets it -> name="viewport"

Like here:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=yes,initial-scale=1.0" />
```

It also helps to specify font size in the body (and html for some browsers), so:

```
html, body {
  font-size:100%; /* <-- equivalent to 16px */
}
```